# Is there `orderBy` filter feature that allows it to handle optional properties correctly?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

Is there a simple, elegant way to order an array as per usual but treat any missing values as `0` (or any arbitrarily set value) instead of `undefined`?

e.g. so that the following code

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:['-optionalKey', 'secondaryKey']">{{ item.secondaryKey }}</li>
```

with a dataset like

```
$scope.items = [
    {secondaryKey: 75, optionalKey: 25},
    {secondaryKey: 100},
    {secondaryKey: 50, optionalKey: 0},
];
```

would produce this

```
<li>75</li>
<li>50</li>
<li>100</li>
```

instead of this

```
<li>100</li>
<li>75</li>
<li>50</li>
```

?

Play with it here: http://plnkr.co/edit/G3nQyEzHfUiiovJTD44Y?p=preview

I realize I could reimplement the entire `orderBy` filter, but that's not very maintainable or future-proof. I could also use a function as a predicate inside the regular `orderBy` filter, but then I would still have to reimplement the complex arguments handling that's already built-in to `orderBy` (e.g. deep key nesting, `+`/`-` reversing, etc.). What I'm really wondering is if there's some syntax I'm not aware of that would allow me to do something like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:['-optionalKey', 'secondaryKey']:false:0">{{ item.secondaryKey }}</li>
```

…where the third argument (`0`) represents the value I want to treat falsy/missing keys as.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the answer was simpler than I thought, as angular's built-in `$parse` method easily handles the deep key nesting:

```
$scope.orderByDefault = function(path, defaultValue){
    var getter = $parse(path);

    return function(item){
        return getter(item) || defaultValue;
    };
};
```

and

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:[orderByDefault('optionalKey.nestedKey', 0),'-secondaryKey']:true"></li>
```

**@TODO**: handle `+`/`-` predicate prefixes so I don't have to reverse the whole array.

Answer (score 0):

The way I'm currently doing this is by running a filter over the array prior to ordering it which populates any optional fields with the default value I want them to have, like so:

```
.filter('orderByDefault', function(){
  return function(array, key, defaultValue){
    return array.map(function(item){
      if( ! item[key]) item[key] = defaultValue;

      return item;
    });
  };
})
```

and

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items | orderByDefault:'optionalKey':0 | orderBy:['-optionalKey', 'secondaryKey']">{{ item.secondaryKey }}</li>
```

See an example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/W9OwBpd7V7syJXkzxnsV?p=preview

I'm worried that this isn't as performant as it could be since I'm iterating/copying the array constantly. It also modifies the original array contents, which may cause side effects and is not necessarily desired. More importantly, it still doesn't handle deep key nesting, which I absolutely need to support.